# Can I upload any content to GCP storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

A friend suggested me an idea for creating an adult entertainment site, and I liked it so I started with the project and I chose GCP for cloud services.
Site should allow users to upload their own content so it should be saved somewhere and that's not big deal but I wonder if given the nature of the content there's some kind of limitation or prohibition of storing certain type of files in GCP.
Anyone knows if so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage is a great option to store files like images and videos. This service **does not** have restrictions about that kind of content (unless of course, the site promotes illegal activities) as you can see in its [Acceptable Use Policy](https://cloud.google.com/terms/aup?csw=1).  You should also make sure you are not violating any  intellectual property rights or the content would be removed or disabled as mentioned in its [DMCA Policy](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/dmca).

As an extra, you might want to take a look at some of the [tech restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#objects) from the service itself that may apply  as a validation for your site:

- Don't upload files greater than 5 TB.
- Use [valid names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-buckets) for your Buckets.
- Making sure you are using [valid file names](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects).